# MBProgressHUD implementation Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

I have MBProgressHUD implemented into my objective-c project and while the progressHUD starts my app crashes. Here is my log

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b35f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101b08deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b3e56d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a8beea ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a8ba98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   EyeQueExam                          0x0000000100e80762 -[MBProgressHUD launchExecution] + 82
6   Foundation                          0x0000000101792eab __NSThread__start__ + 1198
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010568e05a _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010568dfd7 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010568b3ed thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Also this line of code gets a signal SIGABRT error:

```
[targetForExecution performSelector:methodForExecution withObject:objectForExecution];
```

Edit:

```
// MBProgressHUD
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText = @"Uploading to Cloud...";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD show:YES];

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(load) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

---

```
-(NSArray*) load: (NSString *) componentName
{
    float progress = 0.0;

    while (progress < 1.0) {
        progress += 0.01;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you use it? It crashes at runtime in a common way. The object does not response to that selector.

Comment: How do you use `MBProgressHUD`?

Comment: just updated the code... With some more code that i am using.

Comment: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZLoadingActivity just try this, its better than MB

Answer (score 0):

Try edit this code:

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(load) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

To:

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(load:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: @fafafa ok. I will find another way.

Comment: What about `HUD` variable. Where do you define it?

Answer (score 0):

Transform `load` method in `(void)`

```
- (void) load {
}
```

Your code:

```
- (void) load {
{
    float progress = 0.0;
    while (progress < 1.0) {
        progress += 0.01;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```